# module not loaded at boot

Tags: kernel, boot, kernel-modules

I'm on an archlinux 4.4.1-2 and I'm trying to set up a netctl service.
Problem is that for netctl to work I need to have bcma and b43 loaded. 
Since these two are not out-of-tree modules I thought I didn't had to load them myself.

Neverthless I also tried to load described in this [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Automatic_module_handling) here.
Unfortunalty this doesn't seem to work either.
Has anyone an Idea what the problem could be?
thanks:D

modinfo of bcma

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.1-2-ARCH/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko.gz
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8DCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8DBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004727sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043B1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043AAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043A9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004365sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004360sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004359sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004358sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004357sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004353sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004331sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004313sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00000576sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

and modinfo of b43

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.1-2-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko.gz
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev10*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0F*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0D*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0C*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0B*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0A*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev09*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev07*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev06*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev05*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev2Acl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev28cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev1Ecl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev1Dcl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev1Ccl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev18cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev17cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev15cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev11cl*
depends:        mac80211,ssb,bcma,led-class,mmc_core,cfg80211,rng-core
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.1-2-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)
```

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail on how it didn't work? What did you see, what did you expect to see?

Comment: I am expecting to have bcma and b43 in lsmod after boot. But i have to modprobe them myself. So actually without these two modules my wireless card isn't detected and my wlan0 interface is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file `/etc/modules` which lists modules to be loaded at boot. Just add those modules to that file

Comment: Thank you this helped me a little. Because I am on Arch Linux there is no modules file in /etc/, but there is another location where modules are configurated on arch. It is in /usr/lib/ and exactly there, my modules where blacklisted. So I removed a file in /usr/lib/modprobe.d that blacklisted the modules and know it works.